# How to refresh data with my own useFetch?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created my own simple `useFetch` hook to fetch data from an API, but part of my acceptance criteria is to be able to refresh the data...

How can I perform a recall of the data with my current setup?

**useFetch.tsx**

```
const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  console.log('useFetch', url);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      await fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const doSet = () => {
            setData(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
          };
          // TODO: Remove timout, just for exhibiting longer loading
          // doSet();
          setTimeout(() => doSet(), 1000);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, isLoading };
};

export default useFetch;
```

**App.tsx**

```
const {data, isLoading} = useFetch('some-api.com');

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={refresh}>Refresh</button>

       {
           isLoading 
              ? <span>Loading data...</span>
              : data.map(d => <div>{d}</div>)
       }
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more digging with some other keywords on Google and found [this article](https://onur.dev/writing/useFetch-react-hook#h2-manual-refetch) about the same thing.

Turns out adding a counter and making the `useEffect` depend on it can be simple and non-invasive.

So I created new `useState` and a function to set that in the hook:

```
// Best/easiet non-invasive way to kick off the useEffect again
const [refreshIncrement, setRefreshIncrement] = useState(0);
const refresh = () => setRefreshIncrement((prev) => prev + 1);
```

And then add `refreshIncrement` to the `useEffect`'s dependency array:

```
}, [url, refreshIncrement]);
```

I then exported the `refresh` function

```
return { data, isLoading, refresh };
```

Job's a good-un